# buttons in loop, click trigger only first button

Tags: javascript, html, button

i did a loop in which I put few buttons according to the number of colors i've got, but no matter what button i click, it shows like i click the first one, the buttons are unique, i set them id.

html - loop

```
<td> <div> Add 2nd color </div> </td>
                    <td style="min-width:121px;position:relative;">
                    '.$pop['pop3'].'
                        <div id= "'.$i.'" class="btn save_img">  Choose image </div>
```

js:

```
$('.save_img').click(function(){

        onChooseImageClick();
    });

    function onChooseImageClick()
    {
        var rowId = $('.save_img').closest('tr').attr('row_id');
        alert(rowId);
```

the alert gives me always number 1, no matter what button i click, any points to look for the problem? as i tried almost everything, andi  have no clue where to continue looking.

Comment: $('.save_img').closest('tr').attr('row_id');
closest:
"Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree."

will always select the first element since you don't refer to the clicked element but to all elements that have the class "closest"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the closest `tr` of the clicked `save_img` for that you need to know which was the clicked element. `this` inside the click handler refers to the element targeted by the handle(the `save_img` element here), so pass that to `onChooseImageClick` then use that element reference to find the `tr` element

```
$('.save_img').click(function () {

    onChooseImageClick(this);
});

function onChooseImageClick(el) {
    var rowId = $(el).closest('tr').attr('row_id');
    alert(rowId);
}
```

`$('.save_img').closest('tr')` will return all `tr` elements that has a `.save_img` element, then `.attr('row_id')` will return the `id` of the first element in that set.

---

As @John suggested below you can also use

```
$('.save_img').click(onChooseImageClick);

function onChooseImageClick(el) {
    var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('row_id');
    alert(rowId);
}
```

Comment: well, the .save_img, is the "button" that is clicked.

Comment: @user3052629 no `$('.save_img').closest('tr')` will return all the first `tr` ancestors of elements with class `save_img`

Comment: "$('.save_img').closest('tr') will return all tr elements that has a .save_img element" not exactly, it will return the first tr in every .same_img element

Comment: lol, i knew it was something stupid like that, thanks alot, this is the answer, as i was trying to write 'this' in the function and didn't understood why its not working lol.

Comment: you can also use the eventarg in the click function, then you dont have to pass "this" to the function you call in the handler, or you could pass "onChooseImageClick" as a handler immidiatly by registering the event like this "$('.save_img').click(onChooseImageClick(event))" and later you get the clicked element by event.Target 

its a second option, your current approach is just as valid